# Show two different sum columns based on a single column

Tags: sql, db2

Show two different sum columns based on another column.

For this table:

`ID     Item    Quantity    Location`
`1      1       10          A`
`2      1       10          B`
`3      1       10          A`

`4      2       10          A`
`5      2       10          A`
`6      2       10          B`

`7      3       10          A`
`8      3       20          A`

I need to see the total quantities for both location A and location B (to compare which is higher), but only for items that have a location B:

Expected result:

`Item   Quantity A      Quantity B`
`1      20              10`
`2      20              10`

I've been trying this but getting errors:

```
SELECT st.item, st.qty ALIAS(stqty),  
    (SELECT SUM(dc.qty)   
     FROM table dc 
     WHERE st.item = dc.item) ALIAS(dcqty))

 FROM           table st    
 WHERE          location ='b'
```

I can do this easily with two queries obviously, but I was hoping for a way to do it in one.

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: What `DBMS` you are using?

Comment: db2 but I have to run everything through sequel viewpoint

Answer (score 0):

you can use a sum with case statement to do your pivot then a having to exclude rows with no total for b

here is the fiddle
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rS8fgvWoFxn879Utc2CKbu/0

```
 select Item,
    sum(case when Location = 'A' then Quantity else 0 end),
    sum(case when Location = 'B' then Quantity else 0  end) 
    from myTable
    group by Item
    having sum(case when Location = 'B' then Quantity else 0  end) > 0
```